# Installing a gem from Github with Bundler

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, bundler

I am trying to use the [instructions here](http://gembundler.com/git.html) to install a pre-released version of a gem with bundler.

The "bundle install" output lists the gem as getting installed, but "gem list" fails to find it.

My Gemfile:

```
source :gemcutter

gem 'sinatra', '1.1.0', :git => 'http://github.com/sinatra/sinatra.git'
gem 'RedCloth', '4.2.3'
```

Here is a [gist](http://gist.github.com/607816) with the rest of my sample code.

Has anyone gotten this scenario to work?

NOTE: I am also using RVM (on OS X). bundle show does list the gem (and dependencies) as existing, but I am not able to properly resolve them.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the output of `rackup`?

Answer (score 23):

I would look at the load paths, and further debug from there, example:

```
...(master) $ irb
irb(main):001:0> $LOAD_PATH.count
=> 8
irb(main):004:0> require 'bundler/setup'
=> true
irb(main):005:0> $LOAD_PATH.count
=> 112
irb(main):006:0>
```

Bundler configures the load path for you, this means not all the gems are included on your load path by default.

Additionally, from the [bundler git help](http://gembundler.com/git.html):

> > Because Rubygems lacks the ability to handle gems from git, any gems installed from a git repository will not show up in **gem list**. They will, however, be available after running **Bundler.setup.**

Best regards, hope this helps

ED

Answer (score 2):

Bundler might have installed it locally to your app.  This could vary wildly, depending on OS and whether you are using RVM.

What is the output of `bundle show sinatra`?

In my case, sinatra was installed here:

```
/home/marshall/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@3846859/bundler/gems/sinatra-9cfa74a7f352
```

Sinatra doesn't show in the gems list, but the server launches correctly if I execute `rackup`.

Comment: bundle show: Gems included by the bundle:
  * RedCloth (4.2.3)
  * bundler (1.0.1)
  * rack (1.2.1)
  * sinatra (1.1.0 9cfa74a)
  * tilt (1.1)

Comment: Should have mentioned before, I am using RVM and OS X. So I guess the gem is there, the require is not properly resolving.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue using Shotgun and Bundler (git repositories only).

If I use rackup to start up my app, all is well. I am going to investigate a little more and then file a bug with one (or both) of the projects.

Answer (score 0):

Gems installed via bundler on Engine Yard go to a different folder to isolate them.

it's usually `/data/APP_NAME/shared/bundled_gems`

To be sure, check your `.bundle/config` file on your APP folder at Engine Yard